# WCF after executing service method. System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, entity-framework-4, .net-4.5

I am getting the error inconsistently,

1. After successful execution of service method (In between data pass between service & client)
2. While execution service method itself.
3. It will execute **without** causing any issue if the we play with low data [Thousands of data in CSV & DB]

I have google & tried lot in config files, Please help me out if anything need to check in IIS level.

**Scenario:**

I uploading the file(CSV), which contains 1,00,000 (1 Lakh) records & DB also contains 1 lakh records & the requirement is to compare each record of csv with DB records & give the consolidated output which are the records are different(By comparing each fields).

**Client to Service :** File is transfered via bytes format
**Service to Client :** Collection object [Generic List format]

**Technologies & Codes used**
Entity framework-4 used to fetch initial records.
Used normal foreach/for loop for making comparision.
switch used for field comparision.
WCF, Silverlight, c# & .Net 4.5

Below are my settings,

**Service Config:**

```
    <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding_IUploadService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:45:00"
              openTimeout="00:45:00" receiveTimeout="00:45:00" sendTimeout="00:45:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                  realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>

<service name="Namespace.UploadService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_IUploadService"
           contract="Namespace.IUploadService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>

<behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <ServiceErrorBehaviour/>

</behavior>
```

**Client Config:**

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" closeTimeout="00:45:00"
          openTimeout="00:45:00" receiveTimeout="00:45:00" sendTimeout="00:45:00"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport" />
</binding>

<endpoint address="https://localhost/URL/Upload.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService"
        contract="UploadService.IUploadService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" />
```

**Web Config:**

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="2700" enableVersionHeader="false"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
```

**Error:**

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- & ...
```

**Bytes Size**
*Client to server(input):* 10Mb [In bytes format] &
*Server to client(output):* if its small amount then fine else issue [expecting morethan input size]

Also using https **NOT http**.

Thanks,
S.Venkatesh

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight always throws NotFound if the WCF throws an error, because the HTTP response code would be 500: this error code forces Silverlight to throw NotFound.

So, first of all try to debug the WCF while doing this call.
If you can't do that, make the WCF log the error somewhere.
If you like having the correspondent error thrown on the silverlight side, you have to use a server WCF behavior that makes the WCF answer with 200 code even if an error occurred.

More information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar errors in the past and most of the time it was the WCF Service that was failing to: ex some exception not related to communication part of it.

If its possible debug the WCF Service itself; Alternately you can setup tracing using following utility and make sure that WCF is returning the call properly:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx